# mongo.input.query with $date not filtering input to hadoop

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mongodb-hadoop

I have a sharded input collection that I want to filter on before sending it to my hadoop cluster for map reduce computations.

I have this parameter in my $ hadoop jar - command

```
mongo.input.query='{_id.uuid:"device-964693"}'
```

and it works. The output does not mapreduce any data that does not satisfy this query.

This however does not work:

```
mongo.input.query='{_id.day:{\\$lt:{\\$date:1388620740000}}}'
```

no data is being produced as output.

1388620740000 represents the date Wed Jan 01 2014 23:59:00 GMT+0000 (GMT).
The setup is using hadoop 2.2, mongo 2.4.9, [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/releases/download/r1.2.0/mongo-hadoop-2.2-1.2.0.zip) connector version (2.2-1.2.0).

No error messages, just a standard hadoop success message.

**Is my syntax incorrect or what did I miss?**

**Could you point me to some debugging tools/methods for this?**

Comment: this seems to be the right syntax:

    mongo.input.query='{"_id.day":{"$lt":{"$date":"2013-12-31 23:00:00.000Z"}}}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging methods:

in mongo:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(
   function(d){
     if(d.ns == "test.collection" && d.query.query["_id.day"] )
        printjson(d);
     })
```

a terminal-friendly syntax:

```
$ hadoop jar... ...mongo.input.query='{"_id.day":{"$lt":{"$date":"2014-01-19T23:00:00Z"}}}'
```